# What is the terminal command that identifies a modem / fax modem address?

Tags: fax

An HP2560P is outfitted with a Fax Modem [per the spec.](https://verslun.opinkerfi.is/vefmynd/products/HP-2560p-i5-2540M-12-5-04GB-32/info/HP_Elitebook_2560p_Tech.pdf)  Efax-GTK requires the correct address / location of the Fax Modem:

[image]

`hw-probe` returned: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=1f34ac6443

`lshw` returned: https://pastebin.com/raw/E0QX8t3W

`lspci` returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
23:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

What is the terminal command that identifies a modem / fax modem address?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to query the information via [modem manager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mmcli.8.html) with the `mmcli` command in Terminal. For example:

```
mmcli -L

Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/4
```

Note the `4` on the end of the path. Now you can request more details:

```
mmcli -m 4 

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/4 (device id '7d79202d39af4d0e8533a15c8629d4431644676')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Lenovo'
           |          model: 'H5321 gw'
           |       revision: 'R3C11'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts'
           |   equipment id: '358993042510275'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4'
           |        drivers: 'cdc_acm, cdc_wdm, cdc_ncm'
           |         plugin: 'Ericsson MBM'
           |   primary port: 'cdc-wdm2'
           |          ports: 'cdc-wdm2 (at), wwp0s20u4i6 (net), cdc-wdm1 (at), 
ttyACM1 (at), ttyACM2 (gps), ttyACM0 (at)'
  ...
```

The serial devices are located at the bottom: `ttyAMC0` and `ttyACM1`. If you have multiple `ttyXXXX` locations listed, you may have to test each to determine the correct one.